# Why won't this code execute?

Tags: python

This is a program that takes 3 digits, stores them, and repeatedly guesses and checks until the three stored digits match the 3 guessed digits. I cannot seem to get anything past the first while loop to execute:

```
digitone = int(raw_input())
digittwo = int(raw_input())
digitthree = int(raw_input())
digitthree = int(raw_input())
countdigitone = 0
countdigittwo = 0
countdigitthree = 0

while digitone <= countdigitone:
    if digitone < countdigitone:
        print "Digit one could be", countdigitone
        countdigitone += 1
    elif digitone == countdigitone:
        print "Digit one is", countdigitone
        while digittwo <= countdigittwo:
            if digittwo < countdigittwo:
                print "The first two digits could be", countdigitone, countdigittwo
                countdigittwo += 1
            elif digittwo == countdigittwo:
                print "Digits one and two are", countdigitone, countdigittwo
                while digitthree <= countdigitthree:
                    if digitthree < countdigitthree:
                        print "The 3-digit number could be", countdigitone, countdigittwo, countdigitthree
                        countdigitthree += 1
                    elif digitthree == countdigitthree:
                        print "This is most definetly the number!", countdigitone, countdigittwo, countdigitthree
                        break
```

And there it is. Currently, it just takes your numbers, prints the word none, and stops. Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Is the number you are entering for `digitone` <= 0? If not then, your while loop does not execute.

Comment: Why are you nesting the three while loops? And why are you asking for the value of `digitthree` twice?

Comment: @jgritty I see what I did. The problem now is that here `countdigitone += 1` I'm trying to increment the number of `countdigitone`.

Comment: @Padraic Cunningham Thank you! I realise now that I didn't put the increment in the actual `while` loop, I put it in the `if` statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`while digitone <= countdigitone` means unless digitone is a negative number it will never be less than `countdigitone` which is set to 0

I would do something like the following, loop until you find the value of each digit and print the values at the end:

```
digit_one = int(raw_input())
digit_two = int(raw_input())
digit_three= int(raw_input())
count_digit_one = 0
count_digit_two = 0
count_digit_three= 0

while digit_one > count_digit_one:
    print "Digit one could be", count_digit_one
    count_digit_one += 1

while digit_two > count_digit_two:
    print "The first two digits could be", count_digit_one, count_digit_two
    count_digit_two += 1

while digit_three> count_digit_three:
    print "The first three digits could be", count_digit_one, count_digit_two
    count_digit_three += 1
print "This is most definitely the number! {}{}{}".format(count_digit_one, count_digit_two, count_digit_three)
```

Answer (score 0):

The first while loop is doing

```
while digitone <= countdigitone:
```

You've gotten `digitone` from the user.  And you've set `countdigitone` to 0.  Unless they enter a smaller number than 0, you'll never enter the `while` loop at all.